# xpath multiple or wildcard root element

Tags: xml, xpath

I am stuck trying to get multiple XML with XPaths.

Two XML files and XPaths are like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<bq:ProcessB xmlns:bq="http://www.w3.com/xxml/1" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:oa="http://www.openapplications.org/oagis/9" languageCode="en-US">
  <oa:ApplicationArea xmlns:IOutput="com.wm.pkg.xslt.extension.IOutputMap">
      <oa:Sender>
         <oa:ID>A12345</oa:ID>
         <oa:File>testing1.xml</oa:File>
         <oa:ComID>BALON</oa:ComID>
         <oa:RefID>1123</oa:RefID>
      </oa:Sender>
      <oa:MUSIC>TEST-0000-000-0000</oa:MUSIC>
   </oa:ApplicationArea>
</bq:ProcessB>
```

XPath:

```
record.bq.music = /bq:ProcessB/oa:ApplicationArea/oa:MUSIC
record.bq.fields.ID = /bq:ProcessB/oa:ApplicationArea/oa:Sender/oa:ID
```

And second XML and XPath:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<bq:ProcessA xmlns:bq="http://www.w3.com/xxml/1" xmlns:oa="http://www.openapplications.org/oagis/9">
   <bq:ProcessB languageCode="en-US" systemEnvironmentCode="QAS" releaseID="6.20">
      <oa:ApplicationArea>
         <oa:Sender>
            <oa:ID>A12345</oa:ID>
            <oa:File>testing1.xml</oa:File>
            <oa:ComID>BALON</oa:ComID>
            <oa:RefID>1123</oa:RefID>
         </oa:Sender>
         <oa:MUSIC>TEST-0000-000-0000</oa:MUSIC>
      </oa:ApplicationArea>
   </bq:ProcessB>
</bq:ProcessA>
```

XPath:

```
record.bq.music = /bq:ProcessA/bq:ProcessB/oa:ApplicationArea/oa:MUSIC
record.bq.fields.ID = /bq:ProcessA/bq:ProcessB/oa:ApplicationArea/oa:Sender/oa:ID
```

I have tried these wildcards but one works or the other. I can't get both xml to work with a single xpath expression instead of two.

```
*
//
axes - ancestor-or-self
```

Comment: Well, if I understand correct, you are going to use one multipurpose xpath for both different xml, right?

Comment: What about `//oa:ApplicationArea/oa:MUSIC` and `//oa:ApplicationArea/oa:Sender/oa:ID`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two XPath expressions

```
//oa:ApplicationArea/oa:MUSIC
```

and

```
//oa:ApplicationArea/oa:Sender/oa:ID
```

work on both XML documents, given the NS prefix `bq` is defined.

Comment: Thank you! I was trying your suggestion before but it wasn't working. the tool i am using dies with multiple xml. so it wasn't the wildcard. 
Thanks Lutz